# Recursive dynamic programming approach for the travelling salesman

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I was hoping someone could explain how the code on this page works: [TSP-Recursive](https://gist.github.com/KuoE0/3872341#file-gt-tsp-dp-cpp-L16)

The pseudocode is hard to interpret, and the dynamic programming approach makes it particularly difficult to understand.  Why is the bit shift needed?  How can this approach be generalized (for example, given coordinates for locations, can we adapt this approach to solve that problem)?

Comment: I stongly recommend you take part in topcoder SRM contest(www.topcoder.com/tc), this kind of problem are very common there

Answer (score 2):

The bit shifting is because the code is using an int to represent a set, specially the set of visited cities. If you have 32-bit integers then an int can represent a set of up to 32 items.

The basic operations are

```
// add n to set
set |= 1 << n;

// remove n from set
set &= ~(1 << n);

// test set for n
if ((set&(1 << n)) != 0)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `graph` is a map (in the mathematical sense). Given two cities, A and B, `graph[A][B]` is the distance from A to B.

The variable `dp` is another map. Given a *set of cities* **S**, and a city A, `dp[S][A]` is the shortest journey visiting each city in **S** and ending at A.

Once `graph` has been filled in and the final city has been chosen, the function `init` fills in some of the distances in `dp`: for each city A, the shortest journey starting at A and visiting only B is obviously just `graph[A][B]`.

The function `TSP( S, X )` gives the length of the shortest journey visiting every city in **S** and ending at X. If that distance is already listed in `dp`, return that. Otherwise, for each city A in **S**, calculate the length of the shortest journey that visits every *other* city in **S**, then A, then X. The shortest of those is the answer, so the function records it in `dp` and also returns it.